# How to evaluate 1st and 2nd order reactions, with rate constants and fluxes?

Tags: simulation

I want to implement differential equations in C# from Open Cell cellml file. The mathematical model is described in [this article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1367306/). I have parsed xml, and calculate operations, but can't correctly implement the equations. I can not understand how to evaluate differential equations. The format of operations is content mathml. Here is snippet:

> ```
>  <apply>
>     <eq/>
>     <apply>
>        <diff/>
>        <bvar>
>           <ci>time</ci>
>        </bvar>
>        <ci>Casp8</ci>
>     </apply>
>     <apply>
>        <plus/>
>        <apply>
>           <minus/>
>           <ci>J_0</ci>
>        </apply>
>        <ci>J_f0</ci>
>        <ci>J_Casp8</ci>
>     </apply>
>  </apply>
> ```

Comment: Hi Gatym and welcome to scicomp!  It's a little bit unclear what you're really asking here.  Could you explain more about what errors you're getting and what you expect to happen?

Comment: Agreed. We need more information.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is specifying the equation in a way that is going to be a pain to work work with. It look like it is designed to be read by a program capable of symbolic calculation, implementation of which is a pain. It is specified in functional form designed to be easy to convert into a symbolic equation. To interpret from scratch it you will need to:

- Create a representation of variables
- Create representions of + - * / ^ etc
- Create representions of the differential operator
- Implement substitution/evaluations
- Decide how to convert differential equations into a machine integrable form

A class (or function) structure like this is pretty standard:

```
+ Expression
   + Variable(String name)
   + Operation(Expression ex1, Expression ex2 ...)
   + Differentiate(Expression ex, Variable v)
```

Basically, you don't want to do that, unless you have loads of time. Trust me, I have done it myself, its a pain. Best to find a symbolic algebra package. See [this SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721736/c-sharp-library-for-algebra-simplification-and-solving).

---

Once you've done this you can easily write a function that iterates a differential equation. In sudo code,

```
# For an equation of the form d/dt X = Y(x,t)

function step(equation, x, t, dt)
    lhs = equation[0]
    rhs = equation[1]

    return x + dt * rhs.evaluate(x,t)

function euler_integrate(equation, x0, t0, dt,iters)
    output = empty_list

    x = x0
    t = t0

    for i in 1...iters
    do
        x = step(equation, x, t, dt)
        t = t + dt

        output.append(x)
    done

    return output
```

which generalises pretty easily.

---

As for the equation I understand that it says:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} [\text{Casp8}] = [\text{f0}]_J + [\text{Casp8}]_J - [\text{leak of some kind}]_J$$

Where $[X]$ is a concentration of and $[X]_J$ is a flux (and, therefore, itself a temporal derivative).

Solve the equation how you like, using mass action kinetics, or the Gillespie algorithm, or whatever..

Comment: But the equations does not include time parameter, so how can I calculate derivative?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_ordinary_differential_equations